# How to prove that 2 sets are equinumerous?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

We suppose that we have 2 sets $\!A$ and $\!B$, such as that $\!A \smallsetminus \!B$ is infinite and $\!B$ is either finite or countably infinite. 
How do we prove that $\!A \smallsetminus \!B \sim \!A$? Intuitionally it does make sense? but it I cant grasp the idea on how to prove it.

Comment: You're asking how to show that if $A \setminus B$ is infinite and $B$ is finite then $A \setminus B \sim A$? Or maybe you're asking for the case where $B$ is finite or countably infinite?

Comment: "or even": what ?

Comment: What do you mean "finite or even".  The only things that are "even" are integers and the only even cardinalities are all finite.

Comment: @Ian yes that's countably infinite. Thanks and sorry, my bad in a translation mistake. Was sure that's a universal term.

Comment: You can save some typing with \setminus instead of \smallsetminus. And save more by putting \ outside the dollars, but it looks bad when the expression goes beyond the end of a line...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $B$ is countably infinite, let $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be an enumeration of it.
Let $C\subseteq A\setminus B$ a countably infinite subset, and $(c_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be an enumeration of it.

Then the function

$$f:A\setminus B \rightarrow A,f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}[rl] x x && \mbox{if }x\notin C\\
b_n && \mbox{if }x=c_{2n+1}\mbox{ for some }n\in\mathbb N \\
c_n && \mbox{if }x=c_{2n}\mbox{ for some }n\in\mathbb N 
\end{array}\right.$$

is bijective.

The basic idea was that we add the missing elements in like a zip.

If $B$ is finite, it gets a bit easier, we just put all the elements of $B$ in "front" of $C$, with $(c_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ being an enumeration of the countably infinite subset again. Assume $B=\{b_1,\ldots,b_m\}$.
$$f:A\setminus B \rightarrow A,f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}[rl] x x && \mbox{if }x\notin C\\
b_n && \mbox{if }x=c_{n}\mbox{ for some }n\in\mathbb N, n\leq m \\
c_n && \mbox{if }x=c_{n+m}\mbox{ for some }n\in\mathbb N 
\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: could someone look at the latex in my answer? The need to double the $x$ seems dubious...

Comment: I dk...  I tried removing the extra x and it didn't work right so I cancelled my edit

Comment: @DanielWainfleet well at least it is not only me :D

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for any sets $A$ and $B$, $A = (A \setminus B) \cup (A \cap B)$. In your case, you are given that $A \setminus B$ is infinite and that $B$ is finite or countable infinite. Can taking the union of an infinite set $X$ and a set $Y$ that is at most countably infinite result in a set of greater cardinality than $X$?

Comment: That's really just restating the question.

Comment: It's a hint: let's see if the OP thinks it's helpful: restating the question is often very useful (and for all I know the OP may not have thought of the equation for $A$ that I have given).